# building a nested pyparsing.Dict from a nested list

Tags: pyparsing

My input is growing from simple 2-level nested lists to a complex nested list of lists.  I see where pyparsing.nestedExpr() is the bees' knees for this kind of thing, but I'm still wanting to build up a nested Dict structure.

With the basics somewhat squared away I've crafted this:

```
import pyparsing as pp

input_works = '''
(unitsOfMeasure
    (altitudeUnits "m")
    (capacitanceUnits "pF")
    (designUnits "MIL")
    (drawingUnits "MIL")
    (drawingAccuracy 2)
    (drawingHeight 28000)
)''

# recursive dict
input_doesnt_work = '''
(parameterFile "out.tf"
    (revision "15.6")
    (xcoord  1234.567)
    (ycoord  -3456.890)
    (unitsOfMeasure
        (altitudeUnits "m")
        (capacitanceUnits "pF")
        (designUnits "MIL")
        (drawingUnits "MIL")
        (drawingAccuracy 2)
        (drawingHeight 28000)
    )
)'''

v_string = pp.Word(pp.alphanums+'_'+'-'+'.')
v_quoted_string = pp.Combine( '"' + v_string + '"')
v_number = pp.Regex(r'[+-]?(?P<float1>\d+)(?P<float2>\.\d+)?(?P<float3>[Ee][+-]?\d+)?')

keyy = v_string
valu = pp.Or( [ v_string, v_quoted_string, v_number])

item  = pp.Group( pp.Literal('(').suppress() + keyy + pp.OneOrMore( valu) + pp.Literal(')').suppress() )
# some magic - use Forward to make the dicts self-referential and thus recursive
dicts = pp.Forward()
dicts << pp.Group( pp.Literal('(').suppress() + \
          keyy + \
          pp.Optional( valu) + \
          pp.OneOrMore( pp.Or( item, dicts)) + \
          pp.Literal(')').suppress() )

print "dicts_input_works       yields: ",  dicts.parseString( input_works)
print "dicts_input_doesnt_work yields: ",  dicts.parseString( input_doesnt_work
```

input_doesnt_work chokes on like 6, col 5, as if the self-reference in 
    pp.OneOrMore( pp.Or( item, dicts))
isn't being seen.

TIA,

code_warrior

Answer (score 0):

Spotted my error 3sec after posting:

```
pp.OneOrMore( pp.Or(  item, dicts  )) + \   # wrong
pp.OneOrMore( pp.Or( [item, dicts] )) + \   # right
```

Never mind, nothing to see here, move along.

Thanks,

code_warrior

Comment: You can avoid this kind of typo by using the pyparsing operators:

    `pp.OneOrMore(item ^ diccts)`